# Import LESS w/out creating its separate CSS output file

Tags: css, import, less

(I have searched various answers, but couldn't find anything relevant.)

I have two LESS files, say, `file1.less` and `file2.less`. `file1.less` contains import of `file2.less`. Files are compiled into .css OK so I have `file1.css` but the problem is that `file2.less` is ALSO compiled into `file2.css` besides its imported contents in `file1.css`. That is, I have duplicate contents of `file2.less` - in compiled `file1.css` and its own separate `file2.css`.
Is there any way to have `file2.less` imported and `file1.less` and NOT create its own `file2.css`? (I use WebStorm plugin compiler, if it matters.)

**To make it visually clear, here's what I've got:**

file1.less (e.g., contains `body { font-size: 100%; }` and "@import file2.less")

file2.less (let's say it contains `body { background-color: #ffffff; }`)

**RESULTS:**
*file1.css with*
`body { font-size: 100%; }`
`body { background-color: #ffffff; }`

AND

file2.css with `body { background-color: #ffffff; }` (duplicate!!!)

How do I prevent file2.css from being created and just have it imported into file1?

Answer (score 1):

This is something related to your compiler, not a LESS issue. I have never used this compiler of yours myself but I can suggest you to use [http://winless.org/](http://winless.org) if you are a Windows user (or [less.app](http://incident57.com/less/) on Mac).

Winless watches a folder and subfolders for modifications (in .less files) and creates a ".css" based on the file you define as your bootstrap.